# Can we change text color in blackberry Java? I don't think API's is provided of it

Tags: blackberry, fonts

How can I change the font color of a text in black berry?

Comment: in label or edit field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this -

```java
LabelField l = new LabelField("hello") {
  protected void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(0x0511a0a); //here you can add any colors. either color codes (like - 0x0511a0a) or like this- Color.RED
      super.paint(g);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks.
How many functions are there which we can override like you did 
protected void pain()
{} How many are there more by which we can override the default functionalites?

Comment: @AhmadShahwaiz check the API documentation.

Comment: @AhmadShahwaiz, [many of the `Field` methods that are `public` or `protected` can be overridden](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html), to provide custom behaviour.  Things like `paint()`, `paintBackground()`, `drawFocus()`, `onFocus()`, `onUnfocus()`, `layout()`, `getPreferredWidth()`, `navigationClick()`, etc., etc.